# Rails 4 using partials in a mailer view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, partials

I have here a problem with partials in a view of an ActionMailer. They just do not work - and I do not know, if I do something wrong, this is a bug or this is not supported at all.

This should be working as this would be needed to have also DRY code in the mailer views (. From my testings, I see, that helpers are working (after including them into the ActionMailer class)

I am using: Rails 4.0.0 on Ruby 2.0.0-p247

**Error Message:**

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate at /events/81/user_invitations
==========================================================

> Missing partial user_invitation_mailer/test_partial with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:text], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/user/Sites/participate/app/views"
  * "/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.4.0/app/views"
```

But this partial is there! - I am not allowed to upload pictures... structure is:

```
- views
-- user_invitation_mailer
--- _test_partial.html.erb
--- user_invitation.text.erb
```

**Details:**

call in the Controller:

```
UserInvitationMailer.user_invitation(@invitation).deliver
```

UserInvitationMailer:

```
class UserInvitationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  add_template_helper(MailerHelper) # for testing including helpers.

  def user_invitation(invitation)
    @invitation = invitation
    mail(to: @invitation.email, subject: 'Invitation')
  end
end
```

user_invitation.text.erb:

```
Hi <%= @invitation.email %>,

This is a test email see:

<%# test_helper %>
<%= render partial: 'test_partial' %>

Thanks
```

_test_partial.html.erb:

```
"Test the partial."
```

(adding:)
**Not working:**

```
<%= render partial: 'test_partial' %>
<%= render partial: './test_partial' %>
<%= render partial: '../test_partial' %>
<%= render partial: 'user_invitation_mailer/test_partial' %>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rails console give you nice explanation where it is looking for partials:

> Missing partial user_invitation_mailer/test_partial with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:text], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee]}.
>
> **Searched in:**
>
> - "/Users/user/Sites/participate/app/views"

So the root folder for partials is your views folder.
You can create new folder:

> /views/partials/_some_partial.html.erb

and in your template:

> render "partials/some_partials", local_variables: @model.some_variables

or just render full path partial:

> render "/user_invitation_mailer/test_partial"

**UPD**

For complete answer please see comments below

Comment: Oh, thanks for your comment! Actually it does not solve my problem directly - BUT your answer has made me aware of the actual error (therefor, I accept this answer, as it has brought me to my answer).

Comment: The actual problem was laying directly in front of me. The error message is stating ":formats=>[:text]". My partial always had the format "html" - I am wondering now about my blindness ;-)  In the end, the correct answer is:  use a **partial.text.erb** OR call for **render partial: 'partial.html.erb'**  You can may update your answer with this information to make it complete.

Answer (score 0):

in rails 4 you can try with `<%= render 'test_partial' %>` it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but somehow also this does not work. Can I ask you, if you have used this once in a ActionMailer view?

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to find a solution? I am having the same issue. But able to render a partial if defined some shared folder.
Edit - Found the issue. I was not properly closing the call.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately not. But as far I can see in your comment, it is working for you. How? ;-)

Comment: Hi, I had misplace a closing tag. Have you tried  <%= render partial: '/user_invitation_mailer/test_partial' %>